# Input path does not exist error apache spark windows

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark

I am a beginner in spark. I am following a book "Learning Spark By Holden Karau, Andy Konwinski,Patrick Wendell & Matei Zaharia".

I followed the book to do an exercise :

```
scala> val lines = sc.textFile("file:///C:/disque1/tools/Spark/hadoop-environment/hadoop-2.8.1/README.md") 

scala> lines.count()
```

Then I got the error msg "

> **Input path does not exist**: file:/C:/disque1/tools/Spark/hadoop-environment/hadoop-2.8.1/README.md"

Nevertheless, it's the right path... Could you please help me with this ? 
Here attach the related screen capture:

[image: Input path does not exist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'vev checked it - in my Hadoop folder, the file has name `README.txt`, not `README.md`. Change the name and it should work :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this problem with "**Path does not exist: file:/C:**" can happen because you mention the extention of the file but file has double extention or it isnt a text file but the editor opens it as a text file and all you have to do is to add the .xxx or whatever the format is at the end of the name of the file.